# Unable to install libnss3 package

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am running a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. When trying to install libnss3 I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3 : Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.12) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libnss3-nssdb but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first.

Comment: No. That was already executed. Executing this however worked:
sudo apt-get install libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libnss3-tools

Answer (score 4):

First try this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

If that doesn't work give this a shot:

```
sudo apt-get install libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libnss3-tools
```

Comment: You basically copied my comment from 2017.

Comment: Yep. It’s a valid answer 